# How to use a while loop in a switch case statement?(c++)

Tags: c++

So when I put the limits of the integer that the switch case uses I keep getting a infinite number of the output of default for example:

```
int (num);
cout<<"Choose a number between 1-5"<<endl;
cin>>num;
while (num<1 || num>5)
{
switch (num)
{
  case 1:
  cout<<" Good"<<endl;
  break;
  case 2 :
  cout<<" Okay"<<endl;
  break;
  case 3:
  cout<<" Decent"<<endl;
  break;
  case 4: 
  cout<<" Nice Try"<<endl;
  break;
  case 5:
  cout<<"Failed"<<endl;
  break;
  default
  cout<<" Not Valid"<<endl;
  break;
 {
{
```

So for this example how would I make the user choose from 1-5 and if not repeat the loop in order for them to try again.

Comment: Where, inside the loop, do you modify `num`?

Comment: You forgot to ask the user to provide a new input if it's invalid.

Comment: Please provide code that is syntactically correct and properly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop until valid number is given then test it in the switch case.

```
int num;
cout<<"Choose a number between 1-5"<<endl;
while(cin>>num && (num  < 1 || num > 5));
switch (num)
{
   ... //for brevity
}
```

This will loop through the switch cases until a valid input is given.

```
int num;
bool keepLooping = true;
cout<<"Choose a number between 1-5"<<endl;
while(cin>>num && keepLooping)
{
     keepLooping = false;
     switch(num)
     {
        ... //for brevity
       default:
           keepLooping = true; 
     }
}
```

Comment: I cannot edit as I only needed to add 1 character. Your `while` is missing a closing parenthesis before the ;

Comment: After I input a wrong integer and then put a correct one it no longer shows the output that corresponds to the certain case